# Как проверить URL на наличие знака вопроса?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Предположим есть такой URL http://localhost:3000/?category=777&service=55
Как проверить что данный URL содержит "?" (Как вид фильтрации) и получить из этого адресса число после = но до знака &.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const url = new URL('http://localhost:3000/?category=777&service=55');

const sp = new URLSearchParams(url.search);

console.log(sp.get('category'));
console.log(sp.get('service'));
```

Comment: Спасибо. А как всё таки сначала сделать проверку, есть в урле "?" Просто если URL приходит без "фильтра", то и смысла его разбирать нету. Я пробовал через метод search(), но не отработало

Comment: @BlackStar1991, `indexOf`

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался